# Service's promise in AngularJS controller with as syntax

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have problem with below code. I prefer controller as controller syntax and assigning data to this instead of `$scope`. Problem is that it does not work in below case, everything is fine with `$scope.user`, but `this.user` doesn't show anything in template. Did I anything wrong or do I need to use `$scope` in this case?

```
angular.module('services', [])
    .factory('current_user', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.get('/api/user').success(function(data){
            deferred.resolve(data);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }]);

angular.module('controllers', [])
    .controller('myUser', ['current_user', '$scope', function(current_user, $scope){
        current_user.then(function(data){
            this.user = data; #does not work
            $scope.user = data; #works fine
        })
    }]);

<div ng-controller="myUser as myUser"> 
    <p>Current user: {{ user }}</p>
    <p>Current user: {{ myUser.user }}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When passing a callback into a function like that, you can't be guaranteed that the context (i.e. `this`) is what you expect. In this case, `this` is likely to point to the Promise itself.

To work around this, you can either capture a reference to your controller using `var ctrl = this` outside of your callback:

```
angular.module('controllers', [])
    .controller('myUser', ['current_user', function(current_user){
        var ctrl = this;
        current_user.then(function(data){
            ctrl.user = data;
        });
    }]);
```

The above also is why attaching the property to `$scope` works, because it's always going to be a reference to your controller in that context.

Or else you can use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to force the context of your promise callback to be your controller:

```
angular.module('controllers', [])
    .controller('myUser', ['current_user', function(current_user){
        current_user.then(function(data){
            this.user = data;
        }.bind(this));
    }]);
```

Comment: Awesome, how could I forgot about this, more that 1 hour of debugging do to context, thank you!